# Can't boot windows

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-10, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

So I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7537 laptop for about one and a half year, it has performed quite well over the years. But yesterday when I started it, it got stuck in the Dell logo. I ran the ePSA and got the error: harddrive 0 - not install, error 2000-0151 status 32.

Laptop info:
I7 4510u
8GB ram
Geforce gt750m
1TB WD blue drive
Windows 10 (upgraded from 8.1)

I have tried to reconnect the harddrive by unplugging the harddrive connector and back in, this doesn't help.

So is there anything that I can do to get Windows back?

Also if I have to replace the harddrive, does it means I have to rebuy Windows? I do not have the Windows 8.1 key since it is preinstalled and it doesn't come with the disk.

Comment: It may not have *"come with the disk"*, but there was probably a recovery partition and a program to burn CD or DVDs to make a set of recovery discs.  Did you look for a Microsoft COA sticker on the bottom of your laptop?

Comment: @sawdust I have the windows 8.1 activation code, does that help?

Comment: @Red2awn Try to activate Windows 8.1 with that serial and if it doesn't work call Microsoft, explain the issue and they should be able to generate you a new key based from the old one.

Comment: If you upgraded to Windows 10 and activated it using a Microsoft account, you don't need to do anything except re-install Windows 10 and and re-activate it with the same Microsoft account you used before.

Comment: ## I saw all the comments are about getting windows, so does it means there is no way of saving moneyy current harddrive? :(

Comment: You can buy W8 Dell W8 CD/DVD on eBay cheap, a Genuine Dell install disc does not need a key, it pulls the key from the bios and pre activates it on install, then upgrade to W10 again.

Comment: You need to make sure that the HDD is dead. Look for the HDD manufacturer testing tool and run the test it offers. You can download WD DLG [here](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=nMzmzx) .You should also try connecting the HDD to a different system, it could be a problem with the SATA cable or controller.